# Get specified info from my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make a table with all chat messages that have been send to the server.
I got the table working but now i want to get when i click a user name like 'demo' it shows all chat messages that have been send by 'demo'

Im using this table: http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

How do i get when i click like the username 'demo' a bootstrap alert box pops up with all the by user send messages appear? I mean like 'USERNAME GET FROM TABLE SHOUTS SHOUT_NAME=DEMO' and it shows all messages.

How do i do that?

Comment: Should your `shout_name` textarea have the `disabled` attribute set?

Comment: Yes, so people cant edit their usernames that gets hidden when it works. It so i can get their user name and avatar from my other database.

Comment: `$_SESSION['user_name']` must have a `;` in the end, also to show errors for debugging declare `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors','1');` at your PHP file. Errors are hidden by default by php.ini

Comment: I *highly* suggest **not** using the `@` (error suppression) operator.

Comment: Removing the disabled tag doesn't do anything.

Comment: Undefined variable, that's how I see it. Showing full code as to where you are defining your variable(s), would take the guesswork out of things. Here, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. That may very well show an undefined index/variable warning or even more. Plus, make sure you are initializing the session, since you are using sessions.

Comment: **Post..........full..............code,** including your HTML form.

Comment: Okay, i did that this is the output:

Notice: Undefined variable: shout_name in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/test_page.php on line 109

Comment: There, you see, I knew it.

Comment: But.. How do i fix this?

Comment: I told you, post your FULL code and your HTML form. I don't know what your form looks like, or how you're defining it for your SQL.

Comment: Okay it will be a big code but okay. :)

Comment: Just post for the starting SQL.

Comment: I posted it @Fred-ii-

Comment: Thank you, consult my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the variable for `$shout_name`, only for:

```
$shout = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['shout']);
```

where you may have meant to use or meant to add it:

```
$shout_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['shout_name']);
```

in relation to `(null, '$shout', NOW(), '$shout_name')`

which is why after adding [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (as stated in comments between you and I), have received an undefined variable warning.

Also make sure you have initialized the session with `session_start();` since you are using sessions.

Comment: Where do i add this?
Where the code $Shout (etc) also is?

Comment: When i enter it where the $shout code is this error appears:

Notice: Undefined index: shout_name in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/test_page.php on line 108

Comment: @martijnmelchers Add it under `$shout = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['shout']);` where you have the `$query = "INSERT INTO shouts...`

Comment: This error appears:

Notice: Undefined index: shout_name in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/test_page.php on line 107

Comment: @martijnmelchers Another thing. Where are you assigning `$_SESSION['user_name']` to? Plus, is `session_start();` loaded, as I mentioned in my answer. That's most likely the reason why you're getting that, it's empty. Have you reloaded the files? And `if(sizeof($error) == 0)` if there are errors, then your query may not be firing up.

Comment: I get this error: Notice: Undefined index: shout_name in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/test_page.php on line 108

Comment: @martijnmelchers Why are you using a `<textarea name="shout_name"` for it? Why not just a plain input? You probably have some white space somewhere, hard to tell. Do `echo $_SESSION['user_name'];` somewhere, what does it show? or `echo $shout_name;`

Comment: @martijnmelchers Another thing, does the column name "shout_name" exist in your table?

Comment: Ok now i got this code for the username:
<?php echo '<input name=shout_name" class="form-control" value="' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '" />' ?>

And YES my database has the table shout_name (as shown in the post)

Also, the error Notice: Undefined index: shout_name in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/test_page.php on line 109 appears?

Comment: Omg i forgot the " i saw it when i posted this! Now its working thank you so munch!

Comment: @martijnmelchers Great and you're welcome, glad to hear it's been resolved. *cheers*.

Comment: Oops sorry :P - Adding it again ;)

Answer (score 5):

Disabled form fields do **NOT** submit with the rest of the form:

```
<textarea name="shout_name" class="form-control" disabled><?php echo  etc...
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You don't show how/where you define $shout and $shout_name, but most likely you're not validating the form input at all, and are almost certainly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I removed it but it still does not work print screen:http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=igi54x&s=8#.VHN8ePmG9L0

Comment: So start basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST)` to see what PHP's receiving. Beyond that, we can't really help you, since you obviously haven't shown all of the relevant code.

Comment: What do you need? I can screenshot it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `$shout_name`. Maybe your `$_POST` is incorrect.

Comment: Nice comment. Not an answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol This guy's answer makes sense and is trying to put his foot in the door (as it were), seeing that after I told the OP to add error reporting, is now getting an undefined variable. Yet, I'm the one doing the most work lol - see the comments ;) Plus, I don't see Marc working any harder for his upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be grabbing `$_POST['shout']` into your `$shout` variable, but then using a `$shout_name` variable for the insert. Try:

```
$shout_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['shout']);
```

Comment: Weird! This appears: Notice: Undefined index: shout_name in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/test_page.php on line 107

Answer (score 0):

Try this field with a standard post. Turn it into an input and see if it works. It could be a number of things. However try and get something in the database and build on that. If you can't get a standard one in you know there there is a problem elsewhere with your code.